# Backward Euler Method - solving algebraically

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

One of my notes mention that it is "not allowed to solve a Backward Euler Method algebraically"

I have my doubts; for example

$y'(t) = y(t) + 2$

$y(0) = 1$

Then we can compute, with $h = 0.1$

$y_1 = y_0 + h \cdot f(t_1,y_1) = 1 + 0.1(y_1 + 2)$

So is it not allowed to solve the equation above algebraically..? Or did my notes make some sort of typo..?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is rather strange. Is that a restriction for a computational exercise, or a general theoretical remark? In general, it is not possible to find an algebraic solution. One needs iterative solvers. To test your understanding of them it makes sense to implement them on a simple ODE that has an easy exact solution. Thus the restriction to forbid shortcuts. One could also directly demand to solve the step equation via fixed-point iteration or a Newton variant.